# Python3 ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

On my Linux Mint 18, I've tried to install Python 3.6.1 beside my 3.5.2. 
With these commands:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
tar xJf Python-3.6.1.tar.xz 
cd Python-3.6.1 
./configure 
make 
make install
```

The installation was successfully but, now, every time I try to import tkinter, I have the same error:

```
>>> from tkinter import tk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I've no idea how to get rid of this issue, and how remove the 3.6.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you still need to install the tkinker package. You can do this by simply typing:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: really nice answer1

Answer (score 3):

The issue as I see is that you are still calling your `python3.5` binaries which might be set as default python interface. See the line in your error which tells the version of python it is referring to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/
```

If it's a UNIX / Linux flavour you are using, you can check where are your python binaries by using

```
whereis python
```

and you will get a list of all the flavours and places it is in:

You simply call out your chosen flavor to work with, which I am guessing might be

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

and then list the available modules to check if `Tkinter` is available or not, although it is highly unlikely not to as it comes bundled as a standard library.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using pycharm then you can simply write:

from tkinter import *